# form to modify XML data using Xpath

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, forms, xpath

I'm trying to setup a form to allow people modifying some parts of XML files, using standard inputs/textareas/checkboxes, etc; and see the corresponding XML file modified in "real time", in their browser (so using JS)

What I have been doing so far is have an attribute on each form element that stores an XPath to see which XML node/text the input corresponds to.

I can get the xpath value from the XML, but them I'm unable to modify the corresponding XML.

Here is the code :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function updateXml(input) {
newvalue = $(input).val();
xmlStr = $("#xml" ).val();
if(xmlStr=="" ) return;
xmlObj = $.parseXML(xmlStr);
xpath = $(input).attr('data-xpath');
result = xmlObj.evaluate(xpath, xmlObj, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
element = result.iterateNext();
  //element is a copy of the noden I can't modify it directly, it won't be reflected in xmlObj...

  //this will work in my example, but it's too "hardcoded", I want to change that using xpath

xmlObj.getElementsByTagName("person" )[0].getElementsByTagName("name" )[0].innerHTML = newvalue;
var xmlText = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlObj);
$("#xml" ).val(xmlText);
}
</script>
<form>
<input onkeyup="updateXml(this);" data-xpath="/person/name" />
<textarea id="xml" style="width: 800px;height: 600px;">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<person>
  <name>Paul</name>
  <age>12</age>
</person>
</textarea>
</form>
```

In other words, I would like to be able to change the "age" using another input field, without changing the code...

Any idea how I can do this ? or another (simple) way of doing it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Your basic idea is correct: manipulate the document using the XML DOM elements, then serialize back and update the textarea.

The sample code below is still incomplete and needs some polishment before it can go to production. However, I think I have added a lot of useful code and demonstrated how it can be done!

```js
function getElementsByXPath(xpath, elt, val)
{
  var results = [];
  var nsResolver = document.createNSResolver( elt.ownerDocument == null ? elt.documentElement : elt.ownerDocument.documentElement );
  var xPathRes = document.evaluate(xpath, elt, nsResolver, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
    for (var i = 0; i < xPathRes.snapshotLength; i++) {
      var element = xPathRes.snapshotItem (i);
      if (element instanceof Attr) { results.push(val); }//element.nodeValue);
      else if (element instanceof Element && element.outerHTML) { element.innerHTML = val;
           results.push(element.outerHTML);}
      else results.push(element); //TODO
    }
  return results;
}
function updateXml(input) {
  newvalue = $(input).val();
  xmlStr = $("#xml" ).val();
  if(xmlStr=="" ) return;
  var xml = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
  var xpath = $(input).attr('data-xpath');
  var results = getElementsByXPath(xpath, xml, newvalue);
  /*var ResultTxt = '';
  results.forEach(function(result) {
    ResultTxt += result + "\n";
  });
  $("#result" ).val(ResultTxt);
  console.log(ResultTxt);*/
  var xmlText = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xml);
$("#xml" ).val(xmlText);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<form>
<input onkeyup="updateXml(this);" data-xpath="/person/name" />
<textarea id="xml" style="width: 800px;height: 200px;">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<person>
  <name>Paul</name>
  <age>12</age>
</person>
</textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user3594079 I totally misinterpreted this first. But I think got it right now. That was harder than expected.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer, but I still don't get how you reinject the results from your function back into the xml.

Comment: @user3594079 interesting: this only works in Chrome and it looks like I exploit some sort of bug when I manipulate the original xml object via a different document `document.evaluate` instead of `xmlObj.evaluate` - it does not work anymore if I correct it like shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19406071/8291949